# Mantain selected value of a dropdownlist in mvc 5 after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this razor's statement in a view that create a dropdownlist.
How can I mantain the selected value after a post-back to the server ?
I set the selected value in a ViewBag property once on the server but I was not able to set the value again.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Languages, Model.Languages.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Descr, Value = x.Code }), "Choose an option", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: The answer to this question was what actually worked in my case (hard coded id and name of `<select>` to match model's property for model-binding, and hard coded `<option>`s in `<select>` to save database call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When posting back to view in mvc just pass `return view(model)`. `model` is the parameter you are catching on controller from view.

*Update*:
You can also do that view jquery if you have viewbag.Dropdown value like this:

`@if (@Model !=null )
{
$("#DropdownId").val("@viewBag.DropdownListNameFromController")`
}